# Ansible task async with poll=0 doesn't move on from task

Tags: ansible

ansible version: 4.10.0

I am hoping to make this task async on a single host.  When I use poll:0, I had expected it to fire off the task and move on, but it instead takes longer than when async is not used.

```
- name: "setup test databases on cluster"
  block:
    - name: "generate list of databases"
      set_fact:
        test_database_list: "{{ test_database_list | default([])+['test_db%02d'| format(item)] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(1,10+1,1)| list }}"
    - name: "create test database(s) on cluster"
      postgresql_db:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ test_database_list }}"
  become_user: postgres
- name: "install postgresql extensions"
  postgresql_ext:
    db: "{{ item[0] }}"
    name: "{{ item[1] }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ test_database_list }}"
    - - pageinspect
      - pg_buffercache
      - pg_freespacemap
      - pg_prewarm
      - pg_stat_statements
      - pg_visibility
      - pg_trgm
      - pgrowlocks
      - pgstattuple
  become_user: postgres
  async: 30
  poll: 0
  register: postgres_ext_install_status

- ansible.builtin.async_status:
    jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  loop: "{{ postgres_ext_install_status.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 100
  delay: 2
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.start }} -- {{ item.end }} -- {{ item.delta }}"
  loop: "job_result.results"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.item.item }}
```

Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/DTkbbqgR

The documentation clearly states that poll:0 will cause the play to move on from the task, but it instead stays on the task and slowly moves through each of the extensions for each database before moving onto the next task.

Am I misunderstanding the use of async / poll?

The following example works for running async on a single host and having it move on from the task.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: sleep 10s
      command: "sleep 10"
      loop: "{{range(3)|list}}"
      async: 11
      poll: 0
```

How is this different from what I am doing?

EDIT:  Added more code and link to results

Answer (score 0):

Use *aync_status* and take a look at the timing, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: 'sleep 2 && echo {{ item.0 }}{{ item.1 }}'
      with_nested:
        - [a, b]
        - [1, 2, 3]
      async: 30
      poll: 0
      register: result

    - async_status:
        jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      register: job_result
      until: job_result.finished
      retries: 100
      delay: 2
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.start }} {{ item.end }} {{ item.delta }}"
      loop: "{{ job_result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.item }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************

TASK [shell] ****************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=['a', 1])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['a', 2])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['a', 3])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['b', 1])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['b', 2])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['b', 3])

TASK [async_status] *********************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: async_status (100 retries left).
changed: [localhost] => (item=['a', 1])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['a', 2])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['a', 3])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['b', 1])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['b', 2])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['b', 3])

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['a', 1]) => 
  msg: 2022-02-23 01:43:53.697183 2022-02-23 01:43:55.703037 0:00:02.005854
ok: [localhost] => (item=['a', 2]) => 
  msg: 2022-02-23 01:43:53.987039 2022-02-23 01:43:55.993030 0:00:02.005991
ok: [localhost] => (item=['a', 3]) => 
  msg: 2022-02-23 01:43:54.269019 2022-02-23 01:43:56.275290 0:00:02.006271
ok: [localhost] => (item=['b', 1]) => 
  msg: 2022-02-23 01:43:54.592526 2022-02-23 01:43:56.601432 0:00:02.008906
ok: [localhost] => (item=['b', 2]) => 
  msg: 2022-02-23 01:43:54.880133 2022-02-23 01:43:56.886689 0:00:02.006556
ok: [localhost] => (item=['b', 3]) => 
  msg: 2022-02-23 01:43:55.220324 2022-02-23 01:43:57.228616 0:00:02.008292
```

Comment: Thank you, I added what you suggested to see what is going on.  However, all I get is errors from the async_status task for "count not find job".  I have updated my post to include all my tasks and the resulting output of your suggestion.

Is it possible the module I am using (or the way I am looping) is not something async supports?

Comment: I see. All iterations report ``"could not find job"``. I successfully tested the 10x10 matrix (100 iterations) in the shell, i.e. the number of processes shouldn't be a problem for Ansible. The limit might be on the *psql* side, I guess. The commands with respect to a db must be serialized, I think. I'd try *async* with a single db and single extension. You'll see whether *async* is supported or not. If yes, increase the load to see where is the limit. The default of [max_parallel_workers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-resource.html) is 8.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it looks like async is not supported (still getting the same error).  Looking at the source code for the module it looks like it doesn't explicitly state that async is supported and to my understanding if its not there then ansible defaults it to false.

My options appear to be: living with the slowness of not having async, being creative with how the extensions are installed (e.g. a sql file that is generated / executed), or modifying the module to get it working with async and submitting a PR.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to open an [issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.postgresql/issues) and see what the developers think. IMO they are cooperative. You are welcome!